# How can a discontinuous Function have an area?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, area

I'm reading [Calculus by Michael Spivak ·](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/_/7JKVu_9InRUC?hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjwpPLHw5H4AhXo8jgGHSr6B34Q7_IDegQIGhAD), and in the chapter of integration, Author put some graphs for discontinuous Functions and he wrote we can easily calculate the area under these graphs.

My Problem how we can calculate the area of an open disk or an unclosed region?

Images to illustrate Question
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For such examples as you have provided images of, we would compute the area piecewise, and add. I'm not sure how that bears on open discs (nor do I see a problem with computing an area of an open disc). What kind of unclosed region do you mean?

Comment: @BrianTung 
Should any area be fully closed to calculate it ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "fully closed." The area of the open unit disc and the closed unit disc are both equal to $\pi$; the boundary has zero area. Depending on what formalization of integration you're using, it is possible to integrate functions much odder than what you've shown. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The area is defined by the Riemann sum which is defined even if you have many "jumping" points in a function.

Comment: Should our definition include that our function be fully closed and not open

Comment: @Michealgeorge No it should not.   As commented by Brian Tung, following your question, **the boundary has zero area**.

Comment: @trula
another question that is realted to this topic Is the rigour definition of definite integral always the area or it has another definition? because I've read the definition of the integral is Riemann sum but I don't know how it's derived

Comment: @trula 
Any book I've read begin with defining the integral as the area and the derivation of integral depend on the concept of area

Comment: In a picture with a graph of f(x) it is the area under f(x), but that is not the definition. For example if you integrate a force dependent of the path,  so $\integral  F(x)dx $ you get the work done by the force and not an area , so a Rieman integral is the generalization of a sum, and in most cases an integral is used it is not an area.

Comment: @trula 
Then the true definition is a sum, but why all the books begin with defining it as the area not the sum as you mentioned ?